# Referring dll's dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have to create a code where I need to use multiple web service references. All the service references are essentially end points to the same service but for different data sources. So all of these references contain the same functions.

Is it possible to build a solution that dynamically checks the references and runs the same function for all of them. In effect something like:

```
for serviceRef in serviceRefs:
  serviceRef.doSomething();
```

I know this is sort of far-fetched, any help would be appreciated.

Edit(For clarity): These references are SOAP API references, so the method definitions are also downloaded from the web. But since the all the references are to the same service (just for different accounts) the methods in all of them are same.

Comment: Can you name the service client differently and than put a abstract factory pattern over it? I think it will provide you the way to call any required service based on requirement.

Comment: A service reference constructor has an overload to manually provide the binding. So you can use different end points.

Comment: @Silvermind I understand that I have to manually provide the binding, and I will name the differently (say, serviceRef1, serviceRef2 etc). What I want to know is that can I iterate over all of them?

Comment: @DevSharma I am not sure how to use abstract factor pattern, could you please elaborate?

Comment: @ShubhamPandey As requested, I did the elaboration in my answer.

Comment: @DevSharma I do not have much knowledge of abstract factory, could you point me towards some relevant link where I can know how to use service reference in abstract factory pattern.

Answer (score -1):

Try to load the assemblies using reflection.

```
public List<IServiceInterface> CreateShippingInstance(string assemblyInfo)
{
    Type[] assemblyType = Type.GetTypeArray(assemblyInfo);
    if (assemblyType != null)
    {
        List<IServiceInterface> serviceClientList = new List<IServiceInterface>();
        Type[] argTypes = new Type[] { };

        foreach(var item in argTypes)
        {
           ConstructorInfo cInfo = assemblyType.GetConstructor(argTypes);

           IServiceInterface serviceClient = (IServiceInterface)cInfo.Invoke(null);

           if(serviceClient!=null)
           serviceClientList.Add(serviceClient);
        } 

        return serviceClientList;
    }
    return null;       
}
```

Now your main code will go like this.

```
List<IServiceInterface> serviceClientList = CreateShippingInstance("Namespace, classname");//class full name with namespace, you can google for details

foreach(var item in serviceClientList)
{
   item.DoOperation();
}
```

For safe code you can use a separate project for service references.

Hope this will help!

Comment: I had thought of this, albeit without the interface setting, the problem is I will have to manually add any new case. I wanted a more dynamic iterator if that is possible

Comment: @ShubhamPandey ok may be you can use reflection to accomplish that. Try the code in my edited post. Just make sure you are getting the endpoints from web.config and not by code.